# Using the twitter gem to retrieve all tweets containing a certain term, in a certain time window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I've been having a tough time finding info on this since the tweet count was restricted. I've started with this to get tweets in the last two week window:

```
    client.search(
        "to:justinbieber marry me",
        result_type: "recent",
        since: (Time.now-(2*7*24*60*60)).to_s
    ).each do |tweet|
        puts tweet.text
    end
```

This doesn't work. And if it did would only return a certain number of tweets because of the limit. I want all the tweets meeting my query in the time window. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your `since` parameters that is incorrect.  You are passing a `Time` and twitter expects a date only.  It works fine if you do something like:

```
client.search(
  "to:justinbieber marry me",
  result_type: "recent",
  since: (Time.now-2.weeks).to_date
).each do |tweet|
  puts tweet.text
end
```

Comment: Will this overcome the limit on tweets received though ?

Comment: Not at all.  Nothing will overcome the 3200 records you're allowed to fetch.  The only option at that point is to store the data each time the page is hit, then update the view with any new records by only making a request to twitter for tweets SINCE your store date.  That only helps if the search params are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Also Twitter  provides results up to last 7 days window,not more than that.